# how best to show that the user can perform mathematical operations in text fields?

Tags: usability

I need to show pfm users that they can perform some mathematical operations directly in the text fields. like in Sketch App? But how to do it best. if I want to make users don't need to think about It?

Comment: Hi Andrei, welcome to UXSE. A few thoughts about your question: you've described a potentially complex interaction. Unless you get lucky and someone already knows a pattern you can copy, then you're asking for help solving the problem yourself. In those cases it's usually better present the question as "I have problem X. I came up with solution Y, but I don't think it works. How can I fix this or make something better". This is generally better than "I need to make something complex. I have nothing so far. Please help".

Comment: My first question is, if you're referring to Sketch as a comparison, what's wrong with their solution? The answers to design interaction problems are usually best found in describing how a design or idea doesn't meet your goals. Hence my other comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply give them a hint:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvvnFo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The idea is to give a hint with a slightly faded text that disappears the moment the user starts typing their own text. Furthermore upon hesitation (user takes a break in typing) you can display a balloon (if your technology allows) hinting the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What about giving that information [in the field](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups)?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8sdn5.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I did not find proper icon in Balsamiq, something like calculator would be better fit. User gets a hint to use calculations. You can make that icon clickable to open formula builder or helper, if you are open to make one.